# Error connecting to phpmyadmin

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, database-connection

So i'm using netbeans and i have the basic code to make a connection to my database in phpmyadmin but it's giving me error and i can't figure out why.

```
    public Connection getConnection(){

    Connection con;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "");
        return con;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do have the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin` file in the library but it's still giving me this:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql//localhost/test
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247                                    
at bdaysms.Main.getConnection(Main.java:20)
at bdaysms.Main.getContactsList(Main.java:31)
at bdaysms.Main.Show_Users(Main.java:53)
at bdaysms.Main.<init>(Main.java:12)
at bdaysms.Main$4.run(Main.java:272)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at bdaysms.Main.getContactsList(Main.java:38)
at bdaysms.Main.Show_Users(Main.java:53)
at bdaysms.Main.<init>(Main.java:12)
at bdaysms.Main$4.run(Main.java:272)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Is there something wrong with my code or am i missing something to connect?

Answer (score 0):

provide port too

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
```

mysql default port 3306

Comment: I just did checked my port from xampp but even so same problems occur.